# Copy rows based on the condition in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a data set as I've shown below:

```
data <- tribble(
~book_name,  ~clicks,  ~type,
  "A",         10,       "X",
  "B",         20,       "Y",
  "C",         30,       "Y",
  "A",         10,       "Z",
  "A",         10,       "X",
)
```

Now, I want to copy and paste the rows if the type is "X". So, my desired data set is something like this:

```
desired_data <- tribble(
  ~book_name,  ~clicks,  ~type,
  "A",         10,       "X",
  "B",         20,       "Y",
  "C",         30,       "Y",
  "A",         10,       "Z",
  "A",         10,       "X",
  "A",         10,       "X",
  "A",         10,       "X",
)
```

How to do this?

Comment: While I think the idea is clear, the execution is not. Are you looking to repeat *any* and/or *all* of the many `"X"` rows some amount of time? Do you need to make sure that `"X"` has a minimum of `n` rows? If this is a one-off, then `data[c(1:5,5,5),]` works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filter and bind rows

```
data_x <- data %>% filter(type == 'X')
desired_data <- bind_rows(data,data_x)
```

Comment: `filter(data, type == "X") %>% bind_rows(data, .)`, code golf

Comment: `bind_rows(data, filter(data, type == "X"))` sandwich

Answer (score 1):

A base R solution. The idea is to prepare the row indices for the desired output. `1:nrow(data)` is for all rows. `which(data$type == "X")` is for the rows you would like to duplicate. By combing these two parts together, we can get the desired output.

```
data[c(1:nrow(data), which(data$type == "X")), ]
# # A tibble: 7 x 3
#   book_name clicks type 
#   <chr>      <dbl> <chr>
# 1 A             10 X    
# 2 B             20 Y    
# 3 C             30 Y    
# 4 A             10 Z    
# 5 A             10 X    
# 6 A             10 X    
# 7 A             10 X
```

Comment: I've been persuaded to get in the habit of using `seq_len(nrow(data))` where I'd otherwise use `1:nrow(data)`